# how to store input data in an array in C++ using getline()?

Tags: c++

I'm kind of stuck at here, if I have a set of input of student marks in the from of:

```
studentA 20 60 53 32 10 32 
studentB 10 20 30 40 50 60 
studentC 98 93 70 74 83 86
```

I know the total number of assignment and I want to use `getline()` to read the whole line once and store their name in an array and their average mark in the other array.

```
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    stringstream ss(s);
    string cur_stu;
    ss >> cur_stu;
    int mark_arr[maxAssignments];
    int i = 0;
    while (ss >> readin){
        mark_arr[i] = readin;
        i++;
    }
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Did you search StackOverflow for existing duplicates?  Try "stackoverflow c++ read file array" to get a list of them.

Comment: When you used the debugger, and executed each line one at a time, did your program produce the correct results?

Comment: Does it fulfill the requirements and do what you want? Also, you'll access an invalid index if the number of input lines exceed `maxAssignments`.